# Neural Network XOR not converging

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent, bias-neuron

I have tried to implement a neural network in Java by myslef to be an XOR-gate, it has kinda of worked. About ~20% of the time when I try to train it, the weights converges to produce a good enough output (RMS < 0.05) but the other 80% of the time it doesn't.

The neural network (can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwTVc.png)) is composed of 2 inputs (+ 1 bias), 2 hidden (+ 1 bias) and 1 output unit. The activation function I used was the sigmoid function

```
e / ( 1 + e^-x)
```

which maps the input values to between 0 and 1. The learning algorithm used is Stochastic Gradient Descent using RMS as the cost function. The bias neurons has a constant output of 1. I have tried changing the learning rate between 0.1 and 0.01 and doesn't seem to fix the problem.

I have the network track the weights and rms of the network and plotted in on a graph. There is basically three different behaviours the weights can get. I can only post one the three.

[two (or more) value diverges in different directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRlRi.png)

One of the other two is just the weights converging to a good value and the second is a random wiggle of one weight.

I don't know if this is just a thing that happens or if there is some kind of way to fix it so please tell me if you know anything.